# How can we identify used space in log file?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way in SQL Server to identify used space in log files using SQL-query?

Comment: Guys, why are you devoting me?

Comment: My point is about doing a little research ... msdn, sql server books online, stackoverflow ... etc. That's all. Just trying to explain why you got downvoted (btw I didn't downvote you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use dbcc command

```
  dbcc Sqlperf('logspace')
```

On My local Machine,it gave the following..

```
Database Name      Log Size (MB)    Log Space Used (%)  Status
master                1.242188        50.9434             0
tempdb                0.7421875       63.81579             0
model                 0.4921875       81.74603             0
msdb                  1.992188        33.92157             0
```

If you want to know VLF count for each log file and status of each VLF(active portion or inactive portion of log),you can use below as well,but this is database specific

```
Dbcc loginfo
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using

```
select size, * from sys.database_files
```

Comment: This won't give used space

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

[Four Ways to Find Free Space In SQL Server Database](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/zoras-sql-tips/2016/01/15/four-ways-to-find-free-space-in-sql-server-database-/) ([easy to find on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+file+free+space)...)

```
sp_spaceused
```

or

```
DBCC SQLPERF(logspace)
```

or

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE(logfile_here)
```

or

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DbName, name ASFileName, size/128.0 AS CurrentSizeMB,
    size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name,'SpaceUsed') AS INT)/128.0 AS FreeSpaceMB 
FROM sys.database_files;
```